# Is the name of this institute acceptable?

Tags: terminology

Perhaps it is more a question of translation than an academic one, but I think it cannot be wrong to get opinions from people here because the question has a relation with higher education anyway.

A China-based college is officially named (translated into English, to be exact) *Guangxi Vocational and Technical College of Communications* (广西交通职业技术学院 in Chinese), and the business of that college mainly focuses on knowledge, skills, training, majors or programs in strong and close connection with transport (or transportation) which includes roads and bridges engineering, auto engineering, navigation, traffic control, etc. Guangxi is the name of the place where this college is situated.

So the name in English doesn’t sound so clearly defined or even confusing because *communications* might contain the meaning of *transport,* but the word is now more related to telecommunication, media outlets, broadcasting, performing arts, etc.

*Technical and Vocational College* does not seem a common name found in mainstream higher education of English-speaking countries. *Polytechnic* can be the substitute, can it?

My alternative for the above name in English is *Guangxi Transport Polytechnic.* Does it sound acceptable to native ears?

Comment: In the UK, an HE college generally cannot award degrees (they award A Levels, BTECs, NVQs etc- mostly vocational qualifications), whereas polytechnics were all converted to universities and therefore now award degrees. I would suggest "Guangxi College of Transportation".

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use an unofficial denomination, people might not recognize it. Moreover, if you are an employee of said institute, your administration may want you to use the official denomination, whether you like it or not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is unrelated to academia. An institution should know how to represent itself in English.

Comment: I very much doubt that any native speaker of English would assume that "communication" meant "transport" rather than "communication".

Comment: @FredDouglis Please, this is a forum open to the whole world, not every visitor or user here is from English-speaking countries. When English is easy to you, it is very difficult to others. Thank you for your understanding and being kind to a non-native speaker of English.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Please, look carefully, the word used in the above question is "communications", "-s" should not be left out, and you are kindly advised to check a dictionary before giving your constructive reply.

Comment: I'm saying ask the institution,  not us.

Comment: @NanningYouth I'm sorry for getting the name wrong. Actually, the part I misread was that your college, unlike any native speaker, is using "communications" to mean "transport" which I agree is confusing. But, please, watch your tone: telling native speakers to look up common words in a dictionary is pretty rude.

Comment: If the body itself (with its employees and executives included) has the competence or English proficiency like a native, do I need to make such big trouble to ask for help here by losing my own face since I am the president of that agency? You are only your self only, so please don't say "us", because "us" includes many other warm-hearted friends who wish to offer their help. If you do not want to help, there is nothing wrong, but don't make judgment on others, thank you very much.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Sorry if I made an offense, it was due to my low level of the language, but not my disrespect, sorry, again, have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question- here in the UK, we don't use the term polytechnic anymore with technical and vocational training being pursued in further education colleges as opposed to higher education universities.

So, if you were speaking to someone from the UK, it would be appropriate to say:

Guangxi College of Transport.

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean that the word "polytechnic" does not have the implication that this school is an institute of higher education? It is merely a school for secondary-level vocational training without diploma or degree?

Comment: The term polytechnic is no longer used in the UK. All polytechnics were rebranded as universities and provide higher education degrees and postgraduate qualifications.

Further education colleges are probably the closest thing to polytechnics now, offering vocational training in a range of subjects that can lead to higher education university degrees.